# Customize Global Search Box in Microsoft Dynamics Crm

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to customize the search displayed by Global Search Box in Dynamics Crm by applying some custom Javascript to it.
Is there any way to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no supported way to alter the appearance of the search box.

Check the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 Release Preview Guide for "Next generation search".

> This enhanced search experience provides a single list of results across
>   entities, sorted by relevance to the search text, matched to any word
>   across any search enabled field in any search enabled entity. This new
>   search capability will be off by default for everyone. Once enabled, end
>   users will still have the existing multi-entity Quick Find experience, which
>   has been renamed to Categorized Search, available in the user interface.

[Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 Release Preview Guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/5/D/D5D38A09-6A5C-4DC0-8649-3A4F39A8F8F3/Microsoft_Dynamics_CRM_2016_Release_Preview_Guide.pdf)

You also might create a custom web resource to provide a fully customised search experience. This however, could not utilise the global search box in a supported way.